# SQL Express Connecting via Local Network

Tags: sql-server-express

Is it possible to connect to an instance of sql express via another computer on my home network. I have tried but the connection always fails.
What settings should I be looking out for?
What are good words to search on? 
I have enabled TCP/IP
Always get a message saying  'SQL servers does not exist or access is denied'

thanks

Comment: I had the same issue. Check to see if SQL Browser is running [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452850/all-the-reasons-i-cant-access-an-instance-of-sql-2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452850/all-the-reasons-i-cant-access-an-instance-of-sql-2005)

Comment: Here is a good [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx) how to make it works via local network. Hope it helps.

Comment: Another good resource: "Enabling Remote SQL Express 2008 Network Connections on Vista" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/09/17/enabling-remote-sql-express-2008-network-connections-on-vista.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you also checked your firewall? Either allow SqlServr.exe and/or port 1433 access through it.